# Ruby On Rails : How to undo nested_scaffold in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I generated nested model using nested_scaffold. I want delete model `Course`.
   i want all file related to Course should delete. But need `ClassRoom` model. relation should also delete from `ClassRoom`, and also it should delete ***`route`*** file.

> I have used below command to generate nested_scaffold:

```
rails generate nested_scaffold ClassRoom/Course name:string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destroy nested scaffold with `scaffold`

```
rails destroy scaffold class_room/course name:string
```

The result:

```
invoke  active_record
remove    db/migrate/20151006093322_create_class_room_courses.rb
remove    app/models/class_room/course.rb
invoke    test_unit
remove      test/models/class_room/course_test.rb
remove      test/fixtures/class_room/courses.yml
invoke  resource_route
route    namespace :class_room do
  resources :courses
end
invoke  scaffold_controller
remove    app/controllers/class_room/courses_controller.rb
invoke    erb
remove      app/views/class_room/courses
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/index.html.erb
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/edit.html.erb
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/show.html.erb
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/new.html.erb
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/_form.html.erb
invoke    test_unit
remove      test/controllers/class_room/courses_controller_test.rb
invoke    helper
remove      app/helpers/class_room/courses_helper.rb
invoke      test_unit
invoke    jbuilder
remove      app/views/class_room/courses
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/index.json.jbuilder
remove      app/views/class_room/courses/show.json.jbuilder
invoke  assets
invoke    coffee
remove      app/assets/javascripts/class_room/courses.coffee
invoke    scss
remove      app/assets/stylesheets/class_room/courses.scss
invoke  scss
```

Then you can migrate it.

```
rake db:migrate
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I though, you want to create scaffold

Answer (score 3):

Undo nested scaffold

```
rails destroy nested_scaffold ClassRoom/Course
```